# How can i open a TCL file extension?

Tags: tcl, file-extension

I have a TCL (Tool Command Language) file. but I want to run it.
Please help me about how i run this file! what opens this file formats?
Note that i using Windows 8 64-bit

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to _run_ it or _open_ it? A tcl file is a script and running it equates to running the contents of the script, while opening it equates to viewing its contents only.

Comment: I want to Run/Execute it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to install a tcl library first.

You can download the installer from [ActiveState Tcl](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads).

After installation, you should be able to run the script (I already have it on my laptop and work on it almost everyday).

Comment: @4BFORCE Pleased to help :)

Comment: Depending on your script, you may not be able to run/execute it even after downloading and installing from [ActiveTcl](http://www.activestate.tcl), and may receive errors like `can't find package ...`. This is because the ActiveState installation is only a bare bones Tcl interpreter. If you encounter this problem, get a command prompt and type `teapot update-self` and, when this completes, `teaport update`. (The second command will take quite a long time.) Even this may not fix things. I guess the OP didn't have this problem, but the next person to find this question might.

Comment: @nurdglaw - Thank you! That'll probably be helpful to me too one day ;)